Creating a custom time edit box in Delphi
I'm trying to make a simple edit component that accepts 24h time format with autocorrection to the needed format which is HH:MM.
and my approach as follow:
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  i : integer;
  s: string;

begin
  Edit1.MaxLength:= 5;

  i := length(Edit1.Text)+1;

  case i of
    1:  begin
         if Not (Key in [#8, '0'..'2']) then
           Edit1.Text := '';
    end;

    2:  begin
          if Not (Key in [#8, '0'..'3']) then
           Edit1.Text := '';
    end;
    3:  begin
          if (Key in [#8, '0'..'9']) then
            begin
              s := Edit1.Text;
              Insert(':', s, 3);
              Edit1.Text := s;
            end
          else
    end;
  end;
end;

but I do not seem figuring the flow correctly although I'm still trying so I though If someone could figure this out please?
Big note: I do not want to use Masks! or DateTimePickers! I need just to intercept the keys to build the input as above.

Any reason why you are not using TMaskEdit instead?  Or even TDateTimePicker?

@RemyLebeau Yes because I have the code in many languages all has the same issue, beside one of them is also intraweb and pickers/mask seems not working when u apply templates there, plain html inputs also doesn't support 24hrs unless if u add a library which is not matching my GUI or other inputs and if u r going to use regex u will end up in the same matter, so I'm just sampling it in this code as an idea so anyone then can ported it and use it anywhere including me :)

Even if you don't want to use a TMaskEdit, I would suggest you study its source code ($(BDS)\source\vcl\Vcl.Mask.pas) to see how it accomplishes the same thing you are trying to accomplish manually (it is, after all, a custom Edit control with auto-validating and auto-formatting). Hint, it is a lot more complicated than your simple approach.

"I need just to intercept the keys" - let me rightclick on your control and select "paste" via mouse, without using any keys. Then, let me press Ctrl+V on your control. And after that, Shift+Ins. Thank me later.

@AmigoJack Yes u r correct I'm aware of that but, let's just try to solve each problem separately for now starting from the main issue which is how to make it work :)

From a user's perspective I dislike controls that block or automatically delete or "correct" my input. I prefer them to give me visual feedback if the input is wrong so I can correct it myself. From the programmer's perspective I also prefer this kind of input validation because it's much easier to implement: Have an OnChange event that checks the input and show a hint what's wrong in a label or somewhere else that's not interupting user input. Block pressing OK until the input is correct.

One major error is that when on input fails you are setting the field text to ''. That is just plain silly. You should leave the text as is and set Key to #0, otherwise the invalid character will just replace the text.

Why not only allow numbers and : and when leaving the control check it's value and return an error if not valid ? Seems easier and also handles copy/paste

@GuidoG I'll try that too

You need to think very carefully about how you want the behaviour of this to appear to the user.  AmigoJack mentioned the issue of pasting text into the box, and your response was to solve each issue separately.  However, the best way to solve that issue might be to completely change your approach.  It's best to figure out all of these issues at the start.
The first problem I see with your code is that when your event handler gets the second acceptable key, the edit is cleared!
The next problem I see is that if you have both the hour digits and the user types a colon, nothing happens, and they get frustrated.  So, an alternative is to add the colon after they type the second digit rather than when they type the third digit.
But what if you do that, so the edit now has '01:', and they want to change the 1?  Do they backspace once to delete the '1', or twice to delete the colon and the '1'?  If the colon is there before they type anything (i.e. '__:__' where the underscores are spaces), that might solve that problem (people are used to such things when typing credit card expiry dates, for example).
Another problem is that they may use the left arrow key to go back to the '1'.  So they would then be trying to change the second character of a 3- or 4-character string, but your method assumes that they are adding a character to the end rather than changing an existing character.
A good approach may be to not process the key strokes, but to check the entire string after each change.  This may also make it easier to handle pasting.
Perhaps something like this:

After each change, take a copy of the existing text.
Check each character for acceptability.
If any character is not acceptable, revert that character to the one in the copy you've taken.  And perhaps issue a beep so that they know that what they did is unacceptable.

Chances are, there are situations I haven't covered, so you'd need to refine this more, but this may be a starting point.

I'm working on something similar I'll post the updated code if possible but yes still struggling other chances so far

If you want to prohibit a key, setting Edit.Text to '' not the right way to go. Instead you should set AKey to #0.
Doing it the way you do, the invalid key will simply replace the original text.

Yes I found that out and the correction was made
